# not understanding how to use Tree() in Gremlin.net

Tags: c#, gremlin

I'm trying to translate the following example to Gremlin.net (c#)

https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#btree

Example is in Groovy

```
t=g.V().hasLabel('root').repeat(out()).emit().tree().by('data').next()
```

The documentation declares the type of t should be

```
class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.Tree
```

But I can find no equivelant type in gremlin.net

Gremlin.Process.Traversal only has a Strategy namespace under it, and I can't seem to find any tree types elsewhere.

I am running Gremlin Server and a c# project with Gremlin.net.

```
public void Test()
    {
        using(GremlinClient client = GetClient())
        {
            using (DriverRemoteConnection conn = GetDriverRemoteConnection(client))
            {
                Graph graph = new Graph();
                GraphTraversalSource g = graph.Traversal().WithRemote(conn);

                // Builds a small ordered Binary (BST) Tree
                g.AddV("root").Property("data", 9).As("root")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 5).As("b")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 2).As("c")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 11).As("d")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 15).As("e")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 10).As("f")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 1).As("g")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 8).As("h")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 22).As("i")
                    .AddV("node").Property("data", 16).As("j")
                    .AddE("left").From("root").To("b")
                    .AddE("left").From("b").To("c")
                    .AddE("right").From("root").To("d")
                    .AddE("right").From("d").To("e")
                    .AddE("right").From("e").To("i")
                    .AddE("left").From("i").To("j")
                    .AddE("left").From("d").To("f")
                    .AddE("right").From("b").To("h")
                    .AddE("left").From("c").To("g").Iterate();
                //the .Tree() step requires either a string argument (I believe as a step label), or can be used taking a Generic .Tree<someType>() but I do not know what type to declare to match the example.
                var tree = g.V().HasLabel("root").Repeat(__.Out()).Emit().Tree("a").By("data").Next();

                Type x = tree.GetType();
                // x == {Gremlin.Net.Structure.Vertex}
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have bumped into one of the remaining inconsistencies between Gremlin as developed within the scope of a full Gremlin Virtual Machine (i.e. Java) and Gremlin as a Gremlin Language Variant - in your case, Gremlin.NET. I don't think that `tree()` has full support in any GLV. Interesting that you show that you are getting a `Vertex` back as I would have expected some form of serialization error as I didn't think that Gremlin.NET even knew how to deserialize [g:Tree](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/dev/io/#_tree). Even if it did, we don't have a `Tree` object in .NET to deserialize it into.

I seem to recall that problems with `tree()` and serialization went deeper though and rooted into some problems within the Jackson library, but it's possible that those are all resolved now in more recent times.

Note that you will run into similar limitations with the `subgraph()`-step as there is no `Graph` object on the GLV side to deserialize it into. I wonder if in these cases we couldn't just at least default to returning the raw JSON itself. It wouldn't be fun to parse manually, but it might be better than nothing in some use cases.

I've created this issue for ongoing tracking [TINKERPOP-2063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2063).

Comment: I tried about a hundred different things around tree today, and got the serialization error several times, so that is actually good to hear. Thanks for responding.

Comment: So with this being the case. I have a single parent tree structure in the database, and I want to extract portions of the tree from a root so I can draw them on the screen. Tree would have allowed me to retrieve property information into a structure that maintained the parent-child relationships.  Do you have any recommendations for that use case in its absence?

Comment: And lastly, +1 on returning JSON, or some other serialized format at least optionally. My use case requires serializing to json for transfer anyway. C# is a fairly pleasant language to work with when it comes to serialization.

Comment: Well, as Daniel Kuppitz just put it to me, "a `Tree` is just a compacted list of `Path`", so you could use `path()` and then try to reconstruct your own form of "Tree" on the client.